# Laravel: How Can I Convert This Sql Statement to Eloquent or Query Builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I need to convert products price with different currencies to USD. I have two tables: products and currencies.

```
| id | currency | value_usd |
 +----+----------+-----------+
 |  1 | USD      | 1         |
 |  2 | AUD      | 1.077315  |
 |  3 | GBP      | 0.620868  |
 |  4 | EUR      | 0.775338  |
 +----+----------+-----------+


+----+-------------+----------+
| id | price       | currency |
+----+-------------+----------+
|  1 | 100         | USD      |
|  2 | 50          | GBP      |
|  3 | 75          | EUR      |
|  4 | 60          | GBP      |
+----+-------------+----------+
```

I have troubles with second JOIN in Laravel

```
SELECT 
p.slug,
p.price, 
p.currency, 
price * (c2.value_usd * c1.value_usd) as converted_price,
c2.currency as converted_currency

FROM `products` p
JOIN `currencies` c1 ON p.currency = c1.currency
JOIN `currencies` c2 ON c2.currency = 'USD'
```

I tried this

```
$query = \DB::table('products')
          ->join('currencies AS c1', 'products.currency', '=', 'c1.currency')
          ->join('currencies AS c2', 'c2.currency', '=', 'USD')      
          ->get();
```

but got error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'USD' in 'on clause' (SQL: select * from `products` inner join `currencies` as `c1` on `products`.`currency` = `c1`.`currency` inner join `currencies` as `c2` on `c2`.`currency` = `USD`)
```

Comment: use DB::RAW is select for this"price * (c2.value_usd * c1.value_usd) as converted_price" rest is simple in query builder

Comment: just put 'USD' in variable and use that

Comment: Got same error.

Comment: put DB::raw("('USD')") in join

Comment: I would rather try to do this using eloquent, because the problem with DB::raw you create a dependency between your query and current Mysql, if you ever want to change to Oracle or SQLite... you'll probably need to rewrite your DB::raw queries

Comment: Gaurav Gupta - Thanks, you save my day

Comment: @MykolaGlushchenko post same thing as answer so it will help other too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this  `DB::raw("('USD')")`
 in join

```
$query = \DB::table('products')
          ->join('currencies AS c1', 'products.currency', '=', 'c1.currency')
          ->join('currencies AS c2', 'c2.currency', '=', DB::raw("('USD')"))      
          ->get();
```

hope it will work